# chatterbot twitter_trainer ASCII encoding error

Tags: chatbot, chatterbot

I am trying to run the chatterbot's TwitterTrainer on a separate program like so:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import TwitterTrainer
from settings import TWITTER
import logging

# Comment out the following line to disable verbose logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

chatbot = ChatBot("TwitterBot",
    logic_adapters=[
        "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
    ],
    input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
    database="./twitter-database.db",
    twitter_consumer_key=TWITTER["CONSUMER_KEY"],
    twitter_consumer_secret=TWITTER["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
    twitter_access_token_key=TWITTER["ACCESS_TOKEN"],
    twitter_access_token_secret=TWITTER["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"],
    trainer="chatterbot.trainers.TwitterTrainer",
    random_seed_word="random"
)

chatbot.train()

chatbot.logger.info('Trained database generated successfully!')
```

And i get errors that look like that:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 94:    invalid start byte

This program doesn't run more than 3 seconds straight, but some tweets are written to the twitter-database.db until exception occurs.

> Also when looking at the trainer.py i saw this:

```
# TODO: Handle non-ascii characters properly
```

Any ideas about why this happens and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add Python Source Code Encoding top of your file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. These type error will occurs due to this. More information available here http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/encoding.html#fixing-encoding-errors